# Binary (binomial) logistic regression with multiple independent variables: calculating the confidence range or prediction

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

Adding on top to this post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26616/how-can-i-compute-and-plot-the-95-confidence-bands-for-a-fitted-logistic-regres), I am looking for the confidence range (intreval) of the prediction of a multi variant binary logistic regression.

Can someone extend the solution in the post referenced above or provide an alternative?

```
(*Test data (not full set)*)
testDate = {{449.`, 30.`, 0.`}, {449.`, 30.`, 0.`}, {452.`, 30.`, 
    0.`}, {452.`, 30.`, 0.`}, {562.`, 30.`, 0.`}, {566.`, 30.`, 
    1.`}, {566.`, 30.`, 1.`}, {656.`, 30.`, 1.`}, {656.`, 30.`, 
    1.`}, {658.`, 30.`, 1.`}, {658.`, 30.`, 1.`}, {452.`, 34.`, 
    0.`}, {452.`, 34.`, 0.`}, {452.`, 34.`, 0.`}, {562.`, 34.`, 
    0.`}, {562.`, 34.`, 0.`}, {562.`, 34.`, 0.`}, {658.`, 34.`, 
    0.`}, {658.`, 34.`, 1.`}, {658.`, 34.`, 1.`}, {449.`, 50.`, 
    1.`}, {449.`, 50.`, 1.`}, {449.`, 50.`, 1.`}, {449.`, 50.`, 
    1.`}, {452.`, 50.`, 1.`}, {562.`, 50.`, 1.`}, {562.`, 50.`, 
    1.`}, {566.`, 50.`, 1.`}, {566.`, 50.`, 1.`}, {566.`, 50.`, 
    1.`}, {566.`, 50.`, 1.`}, {656.`, 50.`, 1.`}, {656.`, 50.`, 
    1.`}, {656.`, 50.`, 1.`}, {658.`, 50.`, 1.`}, {658.`, 50.`, 1.`}};
(*Model to fit*)
logit = LogitModelFit[testDate, {P, p, P*p}, {P, p}];
Normal[logit]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the basic approach to get confidence intervals for the probability associated with some predictor values.

```
testData = {{449, 30, 0}, {449, 30, 0}, {452, 30, 0}, {452, 30, 0}, {562, 30, 0}, {566, 30, 1},
  {566, 30, 1}, {656, 30, 1}, {656, 30, 1}, {658, 30, 1}, {658, 30, 1}, {452, 34, 0}, {452, 34, 0},
  {452, 34, 0}, {562, 34, 0}, {562, 34, 0}, {562, 34, 0}, {658, 34, 0}, {658, 34, 1}, {658, 34, 1},
  {449, 50, 1}, {449, 50, 1}, {449, 50, 1}, {449, 50, 1}, {452, 50, 1}, {562, 50, 1}, {562, 50, 1},
  {566, 50, 1}, {566, 50, 1}, {566, 50, 1}, {566, 50, 1}, {656, 50, 1}, {656, 50, 1}, {656, 50, 1},
  {658, 50, 1}, {658, 50, 1}};
(*Model to fit*)
logit = LogitModelFit[testData, {P, p, P*p}, {P, p}];

(* Get the necessary information from the logistic fit *)
parms = logit["BestFitParameters"]
cov = logit["CovarianceMatrix"]

(* Generate data points for which you want predictions and confidence intervals *)
(* Here we'll start out with just making predictions for the values of the predictors
   in the original dataset.  I'm assuming that a "1" isn't included already for the
   intercept. *)
predictors = {1, #[[1]], #[[2]], #[[1]] #[[2]]} & /@ testData

(* Make predictions *)
predictions = 1 - 1/(1 + Exp[predictors . parms])
t = 1.96;  (* t=InverseCDF[StudentTDistribution[Length[testData]-Length[parms]],0.975]
              if you're conservative or want to match what SAS does *)
lower = 1 - 1/(1 + Exp[predictors . parms - t Diagonal[predictors . cov . Transpose[predictors]]^0.5])
upper = 1 - 1/(1 + Exp[predictors . parms + t Diagonal[predictors . cov . Transpose[predictors]]^0.5])
```

Using `Manipulate` can be helpful to see the effect of one or more variables on a range of values for a particular predictor variable.  (But "P" and "p" aren't visually very separate labels for this example.)

```
Manipulate[pMin = Min[testData[[All, 2]]]; 
 pMax = Max[testData[[All, 2]]];
 predictors = {1, P, p, P*p};
 predictions = 1 - 1/(1 + Exp[predictors . parms]);
 t = 1.96;
 lower = 1 - 1/(1 + Exp[predictors . parms - t (predictors . cov . Transpose[predictors])^0.5]);
 upper = 1 - 1/(1 + Exp[predictors . parms + t (predictors . cov . Transpose[predictors])^0.5]);
 Plot[{predictions, lower, upper}, {p, pMin, pMax},  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, {Black, Dotted}, {Black, Dotted}}, 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"p", "Probability"}],
 {{P, Mean[testData[[All, 1]]]}, Min[testData[[All, 1]]], 
  Max[testData[[All, 1]]], Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: Manipulate example of p vs probability for various values of P]

When there are two predictors you can also show a 3D plot:

```
Plot3D[{predictions, lower, upper}, {P, Min[testData[[All, 1]]], Max[testData[[All, 1]]]},
 {p, Min[testData[[All, 2]]], Max[testData[[All, 2]]]}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Opacity[1]}, {Cyan, Opacity[0.5]}, {Cyan, Opacity[0.5]}},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"P", "p", "Probability"}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Prediction surface and 95% confidence limits]

Comment: For me the Manipulate only works if I take out the Transpose in lower and upper. Apart from that it works greatly.

Comment: Thanks for the *Accept*.  I wish I could explain the issue with `Transpose` but with a fresh kernel on Windows 10 *Mathematica* 12.2, it works fine as is for me.

Comment: predictors in Manipulate is a list. This cannot be transposed. (e.g. Transpose[{1,2,3}] ).

Comment: Very odd.  Do you have a different version of *Mathematica*?  It works for me with and without `Transpose`.

Comment: I am at 12.1.1.0 version. Anyhow, it seems to not care anymore if there is a list to be transposed in 12.2. Good time to update. Btw. I referenced the code here with Minitab result. It matches! Nice programming and thank you for the work put into this answer. Can you give a reference for the method?